# Why does MS Access 2013 web app dropdown ask to Save when trying to select value?

Tags: 2013, microsoft-access

I have an Access 2013 web app on SharePoint. I have a dropdown list and a button. When a user selects a value from the dropdown and presses the button, a variable is created with the value of the dropdown, then the user is redirected to another form. Why when the user presses the button, they are told "Save Changes - Just a second!" by SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you changed the value in the drop-down list (presumably a combo box control), Access knows the form is now "dirty." If you don't save your form/view changes at this point, Access is correctly prompting you to know if you want to save your changes before navigating away. Make sense?

If that combo box is unbound (no Control Source property), then Access should not be prompting you to save after changing a value here. Provided of course that you didn't change a value in a different control.